# Implementing UIDatePicker and UIPickerView with a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I'm implementing a user form in an iOS app that uses both a `UIPickerView` and  `UIDatePicker` as input devices from a user. I've implemented each of these as a view external to the main UIViewController in the scene and have them showing and hiding using `autolayout` by adding and removing constraints.

Here's my problem: I'm maintaining separate constraints and hide/show methods for animating each of these views in and out. It's a lot of repeat code and I get the sense that there has to be a cleaner way to do this, since it seems to be a very common design pattern in iOS apps. I'm fairly new at this, so I feel like I'm missing something.

Is there a better design pattern than this for using multiple input devices to UIButtons??

Here's a sampling of the code i'm using to maintain this...

```
var datePickerViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var datePickerViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var storagePickerViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var storagePickerViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func storageButtonClicked(sender: UITextField) {

    storagePickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    storagePickerViewBottomConstraint = storagePickerView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        self.storagePickerViewTopConstraint.active = false
        self.storagePickerViewBottomConstraint.active = true
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

@IBAction func datePumpedClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    datePickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    datePickerViewBottomConstraint = datePickerView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        self.datePickerViewTopConstraint.active = false
        self.datePickerViewBottomConstraint.active = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

@IBAction func datePickerDismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
    datePumpedLabel.setTitle(Global.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    datePickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    datePickerViewTopConstraint = datePickerView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        self.datePickerViewBottomConstraint.active = false
        self.datePickerViewTopConstraint.active = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })  
}

@IBAction func storagePickerDismiss(sender: AnyObject) {

    storagePickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    storagePickerViewTopConstraint = storagePickerView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        self.storagePickerViewBottomConstraint.active = false
        self.storagePickerViewTopConstraint.active = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })       
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my storyboard...
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klu9I.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You guys, I figured out a better way!

The thing that I was missing originally is that when you remove views from the superview, all the constraints are deleted. This makes things a lot easier.

I kept 1 constraint class variable for the view that is currently being shown, so the view can animate down out of place.

I also added a "setup" function to get the view in place on `viewdidload()`. Without this the view will always animate in from the top the first time it appears (couldn't figure out a way around this).

Here's what I used:

```
var secondaryMenuBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func setupSecondaryMenu(secondaryMenu: UIView){

    secondaryMenu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let topConstraint = secondaryMenu.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)
    let leftConstraint = secondaryMenu.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor)
    let rightConstraint = secondaryMenu.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor)

    view.addSubview(secondaryMenu)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([topConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint])
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    secondaryMenu.removeFromSuperview()

}

func showSecondaryMenu(secondaryMenu: UIView){
    //Close any open keyboards
    amountTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    notesTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    //Add the view and then add constraints to show the submenu below the current view
    secondaryMenu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let topConstraint = secondaryMenu.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)
    let leftConstraint = secondaryMenu.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor)
    let rightConstraint = secondaryMenu.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor)

    view.addSubview(secondaryMenu)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([topConstraint, leftConstraint, rightConstraint])

    secondaryMenuBottomConstraint = secondaryMenu.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)

    //animate the view up into place
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
        topConstraint.active = false
        self.secondaryMenuBottomConstraint.active = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func dismissSecondaryMenu(secondaryMenu: UIView){
    if secondaryMenu.superview != nil {
        secondaryMenu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let secondaryMenuTopConstraint = secondaryMenu.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.bottomAnchor)
        self.secondaryMenuBottomConstraint.active = false

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
            secondaryMenuTopConstraint.active = true

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
                secondaryMenu.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
}
```